# ls -l command for listing specific folder content in adb shell

Tags: android, shell, adb

there is an issue that I want to create a bat file in a way of opening a folder with adb commands in (dev/block/platform/ ) directory that its only one folder with unique name for each device (**7824900.sdhci** folder in this case), and show list of  files/folders with `ls -l` command, like following command `adb shell ls -l dev/block/platform/7824900.sdhci/by-name`
Now I want a code in adb shell section to --> First opens the directory above then move us to that specific folder after that opens **by-name** directory .

Comment: `ls` of a directory shows the content of the directory. What are you trying to achieve?

Comment: I want to create a batch file that can run ls command to this path **/dev/block/platform/** after that get name of next folder and run again ls -l command for /dev/block/platform/ **xxfoldernamexx** /by-name

Answer (score 0):

You can try

```
adb shell ls "/dev/block/platform/*/by-name"
```